# Rails 4 Paperclip default url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, paperclip

I'm Using Rails 4,devise gem and paperclip gem, my application doesn't want to use default url, how do I make my application save default paperclip url into my database?

I have to add ,that I want my app to save default values for both `:superstarbadge` and `:avatar` paperclips. I want my `:superstarbadge` to be saved with `f.hidden_field :superstarbadge`, I want it to be saved for each user by default, but when I tried to do it then I had `no handler found for "/images/superbadge.jpeg"` error.

So I have two questions,

1. How to save default paperclip url to database WITH `f.file_field :avatar`

2. How to save default paperclip url to database WITH `f.hidden_field :superstarbadge`

Here's my controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
        registration_params = [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:avatar,:superstarbadge]

        if params[:action] == "update"
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {
            |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
          }
        elsif params[:action] == "create"
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {
            |u| u.permit(registration_params)
          }
        end 
    end
end
```

Here's my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable
  # :recoverable, :rememberable and :trackable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/one.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  has_attached_file :superstarbadge, :styles => { :small => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/superbadge.jpeg" 
  validates_attachment_content_type :superstarbadge, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers

  def to_s
    email
  end
end
```

my devise registration form:

```
h1 Sign up

= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!

  .field
    label= f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true

  .field
    label= f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true

  .field
    label= f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'off'

  .field
    label= f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'off'

  .field
    = f.label :avatar
    = f.file_field :avatar

  .field 
    = f.hidden_field :superstarbadge
  div
    = f.submit "Sign up"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Where do you store your sample images? (full path from app root)

   1. Why are you using hidden field if every user is receiving the same image on create? Paperclip will populate it with default url...

Strange thing about `no handler found for "/images/superbadge.jpeg"` maybe try changing it to .jpg ?